# Impossible to debug JavaScript for Word AddIn

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, office365, office-js

I am using Visual Studio 2019 16.10.2 with Office 365

I have created a WordWebAddIn using the default project template and have not modified any code.

This creates an add in which everytime it is activated sets the body text of a word document to "This is a sample text inserted in the document" and shows a task pane which allows some interactions, as shown below.

[image: Screenshot]

I have inserted two breakpoints in the autogenerated Home.js file at lines 45 and 84

```
Line 45 "body.insertText('...')"
Line 84 "searchResults.items[0].font.highlightColor = '#FFFF00';"
```

All is fine the first time I click on the "Show Taskpane" button.

Break points are hit.

However if I accidentally close the task pane and have to click on the button a second time to show it again no breakpoints are hit.

I have raised this with microsoft and they say it's by design, but don't give any hints on how to get the breakpoints working again.

See here
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/office-wordwebaddiin-is-impossible-to-debug/1435407

Can anyone help to show me how to get the debugger hitting breakpoints after a second click on the "Show Taskpane" button?

Comment: Do these articles help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/attach-debugger-from-task-pane and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10

Comment: Thanks I have already tried both of these, without success.